# Setting spinner selection based on previous spinner selection

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I'm sure this is simple and I'm just overlooking or doing something stupid, but I'm saving a number of inputs to a database, one being the option selected in a spinner, and storing it as text using:

```
idCategory = (add_category_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + " Position");
```

Now, in another activity, I'm trying to having another spinner set to the exact same selection. I'm doing this using:

```
private String CategoryPosition

onCreate(...etc)

update_category_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.update_category_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> category_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    category_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    update_category_spinner.setAdapter(category_adapter);

bundleduCategPos = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCategPos");

CategoryPosition = String.valueOf(bundleduCategPos.charAt(0));
update_category_spinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(CategoryPosition));
```

Now when I'm trying to open that particular activity, I get the following logcat error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "N"
```

Depending on the spinner selection saved to my DB, that 'invalid int' letter can change. Essentially, the whole db is being saved as sets of strings, hence the additional text

```
".getSelectedItemPosition() + " Position");"
```

I'm pulling it in, converting to char, finding the first zero-index character which should be the positionId of the spinner selection, and converting that back into an int and finally using that int to set the selection on the new spinner which is reading from the same array.

Would appreciate some dumbed down assistance please.

Comment: Start by adding debug logging and output this: `takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCategPos")`. It probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps you could assist me with this. I'm using
`bundleduCategPos = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCategPos");
  Log.d(TAG, bundleduCategPos);`
but nothing is showing up in the log. Am I doing this right? I assume I should be able to see the output in logcat?

Comment: I've blocked out my `setSelection()` and used textviews and toasts to confirm the outputs. The output of `takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCategPos")` is "4 Position" which is correct.
The output of `String.valueOf(bundleduCategPos.charAt(0));` is 4, which is correct.
When trying to ouput `Integer.parseInt(CategoryPosition)`, it crashes, so obviously it has something to do with the conversion.
Do you know another way of converting string to int?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've resolved it...finding 2 different issues which contributed.
Issue 1 - The selection was not being made when I input the string without converting to int first. I realised the selection was in fact being made, but I wasn't seeing it as I used

```
update_category_spinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(CategoryPosition));
```

instead of

```
update_category_spinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(CategoryPosition), true);
```

Next issue, the NumberFormatException was occurring because I had 3 spinners and was saving 3 sets of

```
getSelectedItemId();
```

to my DB, and then calling them back. I was accidentally calling one of the Id's from the wrong column, so the

```
CategoryPosition = String.valueOf(bundleduCategPos.charAt(0));
```

was returning the first character of the selected string from the String array, which in the above example was "N".